# How to join multiple threads with timeout in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout, threadpool

How can I kill multiple threads with timeout? I write simple version of my script here. I want run two threads that map params to the function. If timeout is over - I want to terminate all threads and move to the next iteration of the loop. But now, I got the result that I not expected:

```
res = []
arr = [6,1,1,1,1,2,3]
def test(n):
    time.sleep(n)
    res.append(n)
    print("test" + str(res))

i = 0
while i < 10:

    res = []
    print("LOOP: " + str(i))
    pool = ThreadPool(2)
    result = pool.map_async(test, arr)
    try:
        updates = result.get(timeout=5)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    except Exception:
        print("err")
        pool.terminate()
        i = i + 1
        continue


    print("end")
    i = i + 1
```

actual result:

```
LOOP: 0
test 1 [1]
test 1 [1, 1]
test 1 [1, 1, 1]
test 1 [1, 1, 1, 1]
err
LOOP: 1
test 6 [6]test 2 [6, 2]

test 1 [6, 2, 1]
test 1 [6, 2, 1, 1]
test 1 [6, 2, 1, 1, 1]
test 1 [6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
err
LOOP: 2
test 6 [6]
test 2 [6, 2]
test 1 [6, 2, 1]
test 1 [6, 2, 1, 1]
test 1 [6, 2, 1, 1, 1]
test 1 [6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
err
LOOP: 3
test 6 [6]
test 2 [6, 2]
test 1 [6, 2, 1]
test 1 [6, 2, 1, 1]
test 1 [6, 2, 1, 1, 1]
test 1 [6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
err
LOOP: 4
test 6 [6]test 2 [6, 2]

test 1 [6, 2, 1]
test 1 [6, 2, 1, 1]
test 1 [6, 2, 1, 1, 1]
test 1 [6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
err
```

expected result:

```
LOOP: 0
test 1 [1]
test 1 [1, 1]
test 1 [1, 1, 1]
test 1 [1, 1, 1, 1]
test 1 [1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
test 1 [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
err
LOOP: 1
test 1 [1]
test 1 [1, 1]
test 1 [1, 1, 1]
test 1 [1, 1, 1, 1]
test 1 [1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
test 1 [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
err
```

...
How can I solve this?

Comment: I think you don't actually mean "multi-processing" but rather "multi-threading", correct?

Comment: Forcibly killing a thread is generally a bad idea, as it is likely to leave your process in an inconsistent state.  A better approach is to ask the thread to voluntarily exit, and then join() to wait until the thread actually has exited.  That does mean that you need some mechanism for communicating with the thread, which could be as simple as a boolean "pleaseGoAway" variable that the thread checks periodically, or it could be a socket or a pipe that you send a character on, and the thread knows to exit when it receives that character.